# Blocking user-agent in wowza session

Tags: user-agent, wowza

I found some user agent in my wowza log, such as "Xtream-Codes IPTV Panel Pro", "Internet TV/1.3.53 (Linux;Android 8.1.0) ExoPlayerLib/2.10.0" , "PlaySDK/5.8.0.8 (Linux;Android 6.0.1) ExoPlayerLib/2.8.2" 
They are from android apps . I would like to know Is there a way to block stream session by user-agent?

I block their IP address but most are using multiple IP address for scraping my stream link.
My wowza server host in centos , I use iptable for blocking user-agent , but they can still access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the only option is to develop a custom module/plug-in that triggers when a playback session is created and checks the User Agent and respectively allow or deny (shutdown) the session accordingly.

Here's an article and some sample code: https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-control-access-to-http-streams-cupertinostreaming-sanjosestreaming-smoothstreaming-mpegdashstreaming

PS: "Xtream-Codes IPTV Panel Pro" isn't an Android-based user agent, it's media server software used for (re-)streaming